# BotBase.add_command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python

@bot.slash_command ( name = "methods" )
async def payments(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
embed = discord.Embed(title='Métodos de pago',       description="**Todos los métodos de pago enumerados a continuación**",       color=0x7532f0)
embed.add_field(name="**Paypal**",
value=
f"`battcompras@gmail.com`**⚠️ Solo F&F, o no recibirás tu pedido ⚠️**",
inline=False)

Comment: @bot.slash_command ( name = "methods" )
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'slash_command'. Did you mean: 'add_command'?

Comment: and i put add_command and it show me this 

@bot.add_command ( name = "methods" )
TypeError: BotBase.add_command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'